# Finding the cardinality of $\{(a, S) \mid a ∈ S, S ∈ P(A)\}$ for $A =\{1, 2, 3, \cdots , n\}$.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

This is exercise 1.6a in *Introductory Mathematics: Algebra And Analysis* by G.C. Smith.

> Let $A =\{1, 2, 3, \cdots , n\}$. What is the cardinality of $\{(a, S) \mid a ∈ S, S ∈ P(A)\}$?

The answer given is $n \cdot 2^{n - 1}$ since there are $n$ choices for $a$, and $2^{n-1}$ choices for $S$, since we can
choose the set $S \setminus \{a\}$ in $2^{n - 1}$ ways.

I understand that the cardinality of $P(A)$ is $2^n$ and that there are that many possible $S$ sets, $2^n - 1$ if we exclude the empty set. The number of elements in each $S$ set ranges from $1$ to $n$, every set yields $k$ pairs which is the number of elements it contains. The number of sets containing $k$ elements is $\binom n k$. So I think the answer should be
$$
1 \cdot \binom n 1
+ 2 \cdot \binom n 2 
+ \cdots
+ n \cdot \binom n n
$$
which I think is correct. I just don't see how that is equal to $n \cdot 2^{n - 1}$.

If you could explain the reasoning behind the author's answer it would be appreciated as well.

Comment: I don't think a close is necessary. OP is clearly confused about the author's reasoning, and has gotten (in their eyes) an equivalent derivation, and wants to see if they are indeed equivalent or where their alternative diverges.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @PrincessEev I retracted my close vote after your edit and comment and answer clarified just what the question was.

Comment: One way to convince yourself that the sum is $n 2^{n-1}$ is by $
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk{n\choose k}=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-(n-k)){n\choose k}=n\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}-\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k){n\choose k}$, doing the substitution $i = n-k$, and using the identity ${n\choose n-i}={n\choose i}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, to look at your summation,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom n k \stackrel ? = n \cdot 2^{n-1}
$$
we can instead look at the more general equality
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k x^k = (1+x)^n
$$
where this equality holds by the binomial theorem. If we differentiate both sides, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom n k x^{k-1} = n(1+x)^{n-1}
$$
and then we let $x=1$ to get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom n k = n \cdot 2^{n-1}
$$

---

The author's reasoning is quite simple. We need to find pairs $(a,S)$ such that $a \in S \subseteq A$.

If we fix a particular $a \in A$ (of which there are $n$ possible choices), we still need to figure out the sets $S$ we can associate with $a$. We know that $a$ ***must*** lie in $S$ (so we already know that $S \ne \varnothing$), but otherwise have no further restrictions. So, how many additional sets $S$ can we build from the $n-1$ remaining elements of $A \setminus \{a\}$? Well, that's just the cardinality of $P(A \setminus \{a\})$, i.e. $2^{n-1}$.

Hence, $n \cdot 2^{n-1}$ possible pairs.

Comment: +1 This does indeed explain the OP's puzzle about why the two answers in the question agree.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see the cardinality $N$ is $n2^{n-1}$ from calculating that $N = \sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}$ is to note that, if $k\geq 1$, then
$$
k\binom{n}{k} = \frac{k.n!}{k!(n-k)!} = n.\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}.
$$

It follows that
$$
N= \sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k-1=0}^{n-1} n\binom{n-1}{k-1} = n\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{l} = n2^{n-1}.
$$

It might be useful to note that the identity $n\binom{n-1}{k-1} = k\binom{n}{k}$ has a combinatorial proof which comes from the two different counting methods used by the OP and the text: Let us write $[n]$ for $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and for any $k$, $1\leq k\leq n$, let $S_k = \{(a,S): a\in S\subseteq [n], |S|=k\}$, and $N_k = |S_k|$.

The two ways to count the set of pairs in $S_k$ are
$$
N_k = \sum_{a\in [n]}\left(\sum_{S\subseteq [n], a\in S} 1\right) = \sum_{S \subseteq [n]} \left(\sum_{a\in S} 1\right)
$$
that is, we  can count how many pairs $(a,S)$ with $a=j$ for some $j \in [n]$ and then we obtain the total number of pairs by summing over all possible $j$, or we can count how many pairs $(a,S)$ have $S=S_0$, a given $k$-element set, and then sum over all possible $S_0$. The first approach gives $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ $k$-element subsets contain a given element $j$, and hence $N_k = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, while for the second, clearly for a given $k$-element set there are $k$ choices for $a$, and hence one obtain $N_k = k\binom{n}{k}$.